# TypeError: sections is undefined in section-config.js:50:30 Magento 2

Tags: magento2, error, section, undefined

I am getting this error TypeError: sections is undefined in section-config.js:50:30 in firefox but not in chrome. 
I added

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block name="customer.section.config" class="Magento\Customer\Block\SectionConfig"
           template="Magento_Customer::js/section-config.phtml"/>
    <block name="customer.customer.data"
           class="Magento\Customer\Block\CustomerData"
           template="Magento_Customer::js/customer-data.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

But still, I am getting that error. Please help me how to solve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a browser cache issue. Please try to remove your browser cache and see. Still, you are facing the same error then you have debugged in customer-data.js and see which section is throwing an error.

Hope this will help you.